# I changed my SELECT query to include JOIN and now I can't edit cells in DataGridView

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2012

Okay I was on a roll here for a while now I'm just stuck. I wrote a query to get some data for my DataGridView, then later came up with a much shorter query to replace it with. For some reason after I changed my select query, I can no longer edit cells in the datagridview control. The only difference is that instead of selecting the entire table of the column I need to edit (the *ITEM* table or *i*), I am selecting a different table and joining the ITEM table to it.

The `ITEM.Amount [Payment]` is the column I need to edit. I can edit it in the first but not the second query . . .

The working query:

```
select ct.[Employee]
, cT.[Employee ID]
, cT.[Case Number]
, cT.[Usual Payment]
, cT.[Scheduled Ded.]
, i.amount [Payment]
, i.Paycard_Date [Paycard Date]
, i.ID [item_id]
, i.modified [iMod]
from dbo.Item i
right join

(select 
    case(ISNULL(e.middle_name,'99'))
    when '99' then e.First_Name + ' ' + e.Last_Name
    else (e.First_Name + ' ' + e.Middle_Name + ' ' + e.Last_Name)
    end as Employee
, e.Number [Employee ID]
, c.number [Case Number]
, c.weekly_payment [Usual Payment]
, c.payment_balance [Scheduled Ded.]
, s.Agency [Source]
, c.modified [cMod]
, e.modified [eMod]
, s.modified [sMod]
, c.ID
from tCase c
inner join Employee e
on e.ID = c.ID_Employee
inner join Source s
on s.ID = c.ID_Source) as cT
on cT.ID = i.ID_Case
```

The NON-working query:

```
declare @paycard_date datetime
set @paycard_date = '1/10/2013'

select (isnull(e.First_Name,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(e.Middle_Name,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(e.Last_Name, '')) [Employee]
, e.Number
, c.Number
, c.Weekly_Payment
, c.Payment_Balance
, ISNULL(i.amount,'') [Payment]
, s.Agency
, isnull(i.Created,'') [created]
, isnull(i.Modified,'') [modified]
, ISNULL(i.ID,'') [Item ID]
from tcase c
inner join Employee e
on e.ID = c.ID_Employee
inner join Source s
on s.ID = c.ID_Source
left join 
(select * 
from item i
where paycard_date = @paycard_date) as i
on i.id_case = c.ID
```

To reiterate, the queries both work, but the "non-working" query does not allow me to edit the ITEM.Amount [Payment] column. I'm assuming this is because joined tables/columns cannot be edited via a DGV control but I'm not sure. I added my VB.net code to update the data once the user exits the *edit-cell-mode*, but it doesn't do much good if the user can't enter the *edit-cell-mode* to begin with.

**EDIT:**
I'll try to explain what I am trying to accomplish. For the sake of example lets say I have 100 **case** files. These are stored in the tCase table. The cases keep track of **garnishments** from employees paychecks. The actual garnishment deductions are stored in the **Item** table. Every week, for each case, a user needs to go down the list and add (or maybe edit) the item for that week. Until an item is created (i.e., until it is no longer a $0 amount), that item's row obviously doesn't exist in the item table. This would mean that viewing a new week's data would actually show nothing, and editing an older week's data would omit zero amounts.

So the query I wrote solves the problem by pulling each Case entry and left-joining the following sub-table:

```
(select * 
from item i
where paycard_date = @paycard_date) as i
```

So my new question is...Should I re-think my method of pulling this data or is it possible to edit columns in a DataGridView even if the column is pulled as a sub-table?

Comment: I did not work with VB for quite awhile. From memory, when VB builds a dataset it tries to determine if the query cannot be converted to an "UPDATE" and "DELETE". It then determines the "main" table that will be "updatable" In your first query the table ITEM stands out straight away, therefore VB can make the grid updatable. In the second case it confuses. If you debug, you will see how it generates behind the scenes the UPDATE and DELETE queries for you. Try to change the second query, so that table ITEM comes first. Also, get rid of ISNULL() for i.amount

Comment: @cha I like that solution, but there's an issue. I'll edit my question to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do.